# Application of Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Assume that a continuous function $f:]1, 2[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the conditions
>
> $$x\to1⁺ = -\infty \text{ and } x\to2^- = -\infty$$
>
> Show that there exists and $c \in ]1, 2[$, for which every $x \in ]1, 2[$ holds $f(x) \leq f(c)$

This is essentially a special case of the Weierstrass theorem (Extreme Value Theorem) where they don't give us the actual function. How do we find the closed interval so that we can show the existense of $f(c)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-\infty$, there is a $r\in\left(1,\frac32\right)$ such that$$x\in(1,r)\implies f(x)<f\left(\frac32\right).$$For the same reason, there is a $r^\ast\in\left(\frac32,1\right)$ such that$$x\in(r^\ast,2)\implies f(x)<f\left(\frac32\right).$$So, apply the Extreme Value Theorem to the interval $[r,r^\ast]$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why did we specifically chose $r\in\left(1,\frac32\right)$ and $r^\ast\in\left(\frac32,1\right)$ and ended up with $[r,r^\ast]$?

Comment: I needed to have a closed interval to which I could apply the Extreme Value Theorem. So, I chose $r$ and $r^\ast$ so that $r<r^\ast$ (it follows from the fact that $r<\frac32<r^\ast$). Besides, when I apply the theorem to $[r,r^\ast]$, I get a number $c\in[r,r^\ast]$ such that$$(\forall x\in[r,r^\ast]):f(x)\leqslant f(c).$$In particular, since $\frac32\in[r,r^\ast]$, you have $f\left(\frac32\right)\leqslant f(c)$. But in $(1,r]$ and in $[r^\ast,2)$ you have $f(x)<f\left(\frac32\right)$. So, in particular, $f(x)\leqslant f(c)$. This proves that$$(\forall x\in(1,2)):f(x)\leqslant f(c).$$

Comment: This seem so intuitive and still a bit odd. So we know that $f$ is defined on $]1, 2[$ therefore we can just pick some values $\delta_1 > 1$  and let's say $\delta_2 < 2$ and then because $f$ is continuous we have that  f is also continuous on $[1 + \delta_1, 2 - \delta_2]$? Could you elaborate on why does the implication $x\in(1,r)\implies f(x)<f\left(\frac32\right).$ hold?

Comment: Because I *chose* $r$ so that that holds. Since $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-\infty$, there is some $r\in\left(1,\frac32\right)$ such that $x\in(1,r)\implies f(x)<f\left(\frac32\right)$.